# Как перенаправить на главную страницу после регистрации?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Сделал плагин, который добавляет шорткод, который выводит форму регистрации пользователей. Однако, появилась проблемка. Необходимо, чтобы после регистрации пользователя отправляло на главную страницу, и всплывало уведомление о том, что регистрация прошла успешно. Подскажите, как это сделать?
Вот код плагина:

```
class RegisterFormByKazzi
```

{

```
function __construct(){
    add_shortcode('kazzis-regform', [$this, 'custom_registration_shortcode']);
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', [$this, 'regform_enqueue_styles'] );
}

function regform_enqueue_styles () {
    wp_enqueue_style('RegisterFormByKazziStyle', plugins_url('/assets/styles/main.css', __FILE__));
}

// The callback function that will replace [book]
function custom_registration_shortcode() {
    //ob_start();
    $this->custom_registration_function();
    //return ob_get_clean();
}

function registration_form( $username, $password, $email ) {
    echo '
    <form action="' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '" method="post" class="regform">
        <p><img loading="lazy" class="size-full wp-image-1604 aligncenter" src="https://test-dev.wolfberrycrafts.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/white-logo.png" alt="" width="224" height="104" srcset="https://test-dev.wolfberrycrafts.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/white-logo.png 224w, https://test-dev.wolfberrycrafts.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/white-logo-64x30.png 64w" sizes="(max-width: 224px) 100vw, 224px"></p>

        <div class="regform-field">
            <input type="text" name="username" value="' . ( isset( $_POST['username'] ) ? $username : null ) . '" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        
        <div class="regform-field">
            <input type="password" name="password" value="' . ( isset( $_POST['password'] ) ? $password : null ) . '" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        
        <div class="regform-field">
            <input type="text" name="email" value="' . ( isset( $_POST['email']) ? $email : null ) . '" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"/>
    </form>
    ';
}

function registration_validation( $username, $password, $email )  {
    global $reg_errors;
    $reg_errors = new WP_Error;

    if ( empty( $username ) || empty( $password ) || empty( $email ) ) {
        $reg_errors->add('field', 'Required form field is missing');
    }
    if ( 4 > strlen( $username ) ) {
        $reg_errors->add( 'username_length', 'Username too short. At least 4 characters is required' );
    }
    if ( username_exists( $username ) )
        $reg_errors->add('user_name', 'Sorry, that username already exists!');
    if ( ! validate_username( $username ) ) {
        $reg_errors->add( 'username_invalid', 'Sorry, the username you entered is not valid' );
    }
    if ( 5 > strlen( $password ) ) {
        $reg_errors->add( 'password', 'Password length must be greater than 5' );
    }
    if ( !is_email( $email ) ) {
        $reg_errors->add( 'email_invalid', 'Email is not valid' );
    }
    if ( email_exists( $email ) ) {
        $reg_errors->add( 'email', 'Email Already in use' );
    }
    if ( is_wp_error( $reg_errors ) ) {

        foreach ( $reg_errors->get_error_messages() as $error ) {
          
            echo '<div>';
            echo '<strong>ERROR</strong>:';
            echo $error . '<br/>';
            echo '</div>';
              
        }
      
    }
}

function complete_registration() {
    global $reg_errors, $username, $password, $email;
    if ( 1 > count( $reg_errors->get_error_messages() ) ) {
        $userdata = array(
        'user_login'    =>   $username,
        'user_email'    =>   $email,
        'user_pass'     =>   $password,
        );
        $user = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
    }
}

function custom_registration_function() {
    if ( isset($_POST['submit'] ) ) {
        $this->registration_validation(
        $_POST['username'],
        $_POST['password'],
        $_POST['email'],
        );
          
        // sanitize user form input
        global $username, $password, $email;
        $username   =   sanitize_user( $_POST['username'] );
        $password   =   esc_attr( $_POST['password'] );
        $email      =   sanitize_email( $_POST['email'] );
  
        // call @function complete_registration to create the user
        // only when no WP_error is found
        $this->complete_registration(
        $username,
        $password,
        $email,
        ); 
        
    }
    
    

    $this->registration_form(
        $username,
        $password,
        $email,
        );
}
```

}

Comment: Жуть какая-то.. Начинай с https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_login_form https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_new_user https://wp-kama.ru/hook/register_new_user и тд.. (и вообще сейчас форму логина можно даже мышей вывести где угодно)

Comment: Я правильное понял, мне всего лишь надо использовать вот ту форму, в конце? Я вывожу ее, но ни чего не происходит. Регистрация не происходит. Если точнее, я просто вывожу ее шорткодом на странице, и пытаюсь зарегистрироваться. Но ни чего не происходит. Просто перезагружается страница.

Comment: Я вообще не понимаю зачем тебе понадобилось изобретать двухрульный велосипед с треугольным колёсами (ака своя форма, шорткоды и пр.). Форма логина выводится в редакторе (да и вообще в любое место страницы) парой кликов мыши. (Не хочешь из админки - можно вставить первую данную функцию в нужное тебе место). Достаточно её кастомизировать, и это делается намного проще, а главное - правильнее, того, что ты наваял.